# linking directly to comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

[The "activity" tab](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/409?tab=activity)'s "comment" log entries (for comments on answers only, not for comments on questions) link to things like [`https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5991/words-often-mispronounced/7274#comment-8895`](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5991/words-often-mispronounced/7274#comment-8895), with an anchor named `comment-[number]`. These anchors don't work: the page's source code doesn't include any such anchor. IMO either the link should merely link to the answer or the source code should include the anchors linked to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well... It's not quite that simple. Comments *can* be linked to, if they're on a page - they all have IDs of the form `comment-[number]`, and this'll work just fine for the URL fragment. Try this one:

[`https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7279/do-jewish-people-keep-a-bible-or-other-scripture-in-their-homes/7280#comment-8805`](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7279/do-jewish-people-keep-a-bible-or-other-scripture-in-their-homes/7280#comment-8805)

...The problem is, comments *aren't always displayed*. If there are too many comments on a given answer, some of them will be hidden. If there are too many *answers* on a question, comments that aren't up-voted will be hidden for all the answers.

There's an open request [to automatically expand comments on an answer when that answer is linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71182/auto-expand-comments-of-specific-answer-when-browsing-directly-to-that-answer) which would (mostly) resolve this. If it bothers you, vote for it...